# How to make 3 textView control to be on the same size

Tags: android, android-layout

In my activity I defined 3 textView control.
All those textView appears one next to the other - and I need to do something that they will be always on the same size. lets say that the first textView control is the hour and the second textView control is the minutes and the third textView control is the seconds.

so I want to show them on full screen and all the textView controls need to be on the same size.

How to do it ?

Comment: use linear layout with weight sum

Comment: you want the textview in the same row with same width ?

Comment: @ user3676184 - Thanks !!! - used the 'sum' and solve the issue

Comment: `weightSum` is not Required if you give equal `weight` to all `TextView`

Comment: @Yanshof You may have to post screenshot of your need. **HH:mm:ss** is also have same size if you just set **horizontally** `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weightsum is not needed if they are placed within a linearlayout, orientation horizontal with wrap content for width and height, if they are using the same theme style for text.

Also by wrapping the width and height of the container layout of the textviews, this is not going to force the the view to fill any particular space, other than what is needed for the textviews.

Note the linear layout is within the view layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hh:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mm:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ss"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have read question properly? He said that **I want to show them on full screen and all the textView controls need to be on the same size.**

Answer (score 2):

Use One `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation.

And give `layout_weight="1"`in all `TextView`.

This will show you your `TextView` in one line with same width.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hour Text"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Minute Text"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Text"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will showing like bellow image with same width.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can set there width and height as `fill_parent` and set weight to all of the textView as 1 like this in your layout

```
 android:weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="90"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text 1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text 2"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:text="Text 3"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to adjust the width of the three textviews. for that you have to use a parent LinearLayout and you have to play with layout_weight,

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

this will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Appear like:

[image]